# javascript simple assertEqual test run result

Tags: javascript, testing

I am learning JS and this is something I could not understand even after watching tutorials online.

the function `assertEqual` compare actual and expected values with strict equality, then log one of two messages to the console.

```
function assertEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
    if (actual === expected) {
        console.log("passed")
    } else {
        console.log('FAILED [' + testName + '] Expected "' + expected + '", but got "' + actual + '"')
    }
}
```

The test case is supposed to return `passed` and `FAILED` respectively.

```
function multiplyByTwo(n) {
    return n * 2;
}
var output = multiplyByTwo(2); // returns 4
assertEqual(output, 4, 'it doubles 2 to 4');
// console output:
// passed

function multiplyByTwo(n) {
    return (n * 2) + 1; // an incorrect implementation
}
var output = multiplyByTwo(2); // returns 5
assertEqual(output, 4, 'it doubles 2 to 4');
// console output:
// FAILED [it doubles 2 to 4] Expected "4", but got "5"
```

however, the results are both `failed`...

```
FAILED [it doubles 2 to 4] Expected "4", but got "5"
FAILED [it doubles 2 to 4] Expected "4", but got "5"
```

If I change the test case, however, with variable names like below...

```
let actualOne = multiplyByTwo(2)
let expectedOne = 4;
let testNameOne = 'it doubles 2 to 4'

assertEqual(actualOne, expectedOne, testNameOne) // passed

let actualTwo = multiplyByTwo(2)
let expectedTwo = 5;
let testNameTwo = 'it doubles 2 to 4'

assertEqual(actualTwo, expectedTwo, testNameTwo)
```

these returns

```
FAILED [it doubles 2 to 4] Expected "4", but got "5"
passed
```

So my question is, why does the first trial not work? What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that you are using the same name for both of the functions to be tested. Javascript does something called "function hoisting". To explain simply, it moves all the functions declared in a block to the top of the block. In this case, since you are declaring two functions with the same name, they both get moved to the top, the second one overrides the first, and the second declaration is actually called for both of the tests. TLDR; use different names for different functions.